# state is updated but not getting in other handler in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

There is two handler copy Handler and paste Handler, in copy Handler i want to change the copy state with props and want to console copy.

I tried but in console i am getting null not updated value of copy.

Here is my code i have tried.In my project i am tring to copy one card Id and pass to other card.
Here in above example i am getting the updated value in the console but i my project i am using the same thing. In my project there are some cards i am getting from my an array. On clicking one card i want to get the clicked card id and pass to other card.

So please help me to fix this issue.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Dummy extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      copy: null
    };
  }

  copyHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ copy: this.props.mname });
    // updating the props
  };
  pasteHandler = () => {
    console.log(this.state.copy);
    // getting null
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button className="btn" onClick={this.copyHandler}>
          {" "}
          copy
        </button>
        <button className="btn" onClick={this.pasteHandler}>
          {" "}
          paste
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dummy;
```

Here in above example i am getting the updated value in the console but i my project i am using the same thing. In my project there are some cards i am getting from my an array. On clicking one card i want to get the clicked card id and pass to other card.

So please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you console log the `this.props.mname`? Does it has any value?

Comment: I have set the mname props in parent component like <Parent mname='something'> <Parent>

Comment: mname is a prop of Dummy component? Why do you set mname prop for Parent component?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the state and props values are not up to date values while setting a state. You have to use another version of `setState`.

```
this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    const newState = { ...prevState, copy: props.mname };
    return newState;
});
```

Comment: I tried console.log(this.state.copy) in other handler but got undefined.

Comment: Before your `setState`, try to add `console.log(this.props.mname)`. If this is null, then you are not sending it properly from the parent component. As @Hải Bùi mentioned in the comment under the question, you shouldn't add the property on the parent. Instead of `<ParentComponent mname='test' />`, add `<Dummy mname='test' />`

Comment: Or if it should be `<ParentComponent mname='test'/>`, you should use `<Dummy mname={this.props.mname} />`